# Access every window's rendering area

Tags: windows, opengl, directx, render, target

What is the best way to access the rendering area of every single window in Microsoft Windows, so I can render them myself in 3D? I know the Desktop Window Manager (dwm) gives every window a rendertarget and renders them alltogether on the screen.
There are tons of 3D window managers out there, but finding some code or other information is hard for me, so I'm asking you.
I would like to do it in OpenGL, but I can imagine it's just possible in DirectX, but that's fine too.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the operaring system / graphics system specific API dedicated for that task. OpenGL is operating and graphics system agnostic and has no notion of "windows".

In Windows the API you must use is the DWM API. For Windows versions predating the DWM API (XP and earlier) some "dirty" hacks have to be employed to get the contents of the windows (essentially hooking the WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBACKGROUND messages, and the BeginPaint and EndPaint functions of the GDI to copy the windows' contents into a DIBSECTION that can be used for updating a texture).

In X11 the API to use is XComposite + the GLX_ARB_texture_from_pixmap extension